# A character to indicate a sharp intake of breath

Tags: punctuation

Is there a character in any established alphabet (I couldn't find anything in the IPA) to denote a sharp intake of breath, as if by surprise?

I want to include it in a character's name. Initially I thought "!" would suffice, making the name, for example, "!Davis" (pronounced -breath-Davis) based on its usage in demonyms like "!Kung-San", but it seems I have mis-remembered what the exclamation point here does.

Googling just gives me information on "a sharp intake of breath", which I'm sure is wonderful but is of little use to me at the time of writing. Thanks.

Comment: You might take a look at the Wikipedia article on [implosive consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implosive_consonant); it may not be exactly what you want, but I doubt you'll have a lot of phoneticians yelling at you if you steal one of the IPA characters for your own conlang.

Comment: "..That is, the airstream is controlled by moving the glottis downward in addition to expelling air from the lungs." - Thanks, but I'm looking for intake, not exhalation.

Comment: Read farther and you will see that dropping the glottis is thought to draw air inward at the beginning of the consonant -- hence *implosive* as opposed to *explosive*. By the way, the <!> denotes a 'click' consonant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you should feel free to use symbols creatively
in creative writing , , ,

- The ! exclamation point in !Kung denotes a
  [click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_clicks).
- Musical notation comes close to what you want,
  with an **'** apostrophe called a *comma* or
  [*breath mark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breath_mark),
  often played/sung as a gasp, though it comes at the
  end of a note and not the beginning.  The English use of
   'postrophe to denote a truncated sound
  seems close to what you want, and you could make it bold
  for **'**xtra **'**mpact.
- Have you considered a mark over the first letter, like the
  ˇ caron/hacek on Ď ?

Comment: Thank you - an apostrophe is not a unique symbol, which is what I would have preferred, but it's _established_, which is the end goal of this. Much obliged.